# PHP Session. Unable to get to log-in

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

**--EDIT--**

Found the issue. Thanks to Conyc.
I think I found the issue. mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) returns null when there are no more rows left to read. This means that $row will be null when you are trying to put the username into the session at $_SESSION['Id'] = $row['Username']; Try to store the username in a variable like you do with the password. – Conyc 12 mins ago

---

Currently trying to show content by logging on. I'm utilizing sessions and hashed passwords. I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not displaying that I'm "logged in".  if (isset($_SESSION['Id'])) is displaying that I am not logged in, even though I can retrieve my username and password from mysql. I think it may have something to do with sessions on html? Or perhaps the session id is wrong? Idk. If you guys have any ideas I would love to know. I'm kinda new to php so it's been pretty rough.

Here is my login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$user = $_POST['User'];
$Userpassword = $_POST['Password'];
$password_hash = password_hash($Userpassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$storedPassword = "";

// Create connection

$conn= mysqli_connect("$servername","$username","$password") or die ("could 
not connect to mysql");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "dpw_recyclopedia") or die ("no database");
$sql = "SELECT Username, Password FROM Users WHERE Username = '".$user."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if(! $result ) {
    die('Could not select data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //echo "user: " . $row["UserName"]. " " . $row["Password"]. "<br>";
        $storedPassword = $row["Password"];
    }
} else {
    echo "User Not Found";
}

 if (password_verify($Userpassword , $storedPassword)) {
    $_SESSION['Id'] = $row['Username'];
    header ("Location: 'mywebsite');
 }else {
    header ("Location: 'mywebsite');
    exit();

 }

?>
```

Here is my html page

```
<?php
include 'DbConfig.php';
session_name('Id');
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

                    <?php

                        if (isset($_SESSION['Id'])){
                                echo "you are logged in";
                            } else {
                                echo "you are not logged in";
                    }

                    echo json_encode($_SESSION);
                    echo json_encode($_COOKIE);
                    ?>
                        <form method = 'POST' action="./ajax/login.php">
                        <input type='text' name='User' placeholder='Email'>
                        <input type='password' name= 'Password' 
placeholder='Password'>
                        <button type='submit'  name='my_form_submit_button'>
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span> 
&nbsp; Sign In
                        </button>
                        </form>

                        <form method = 'POST' action="./ajax/logout.php">
                        <button type='submit'  name='my_form_submit_button'>
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span> 
&nbsp; Sign Out
                        </button>
                        </form>


</html>
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but it looks like you created your `header()` wrong.  It should be `header('Location:mywebsite');`

Comment: where is your password_verify function? And how does $_SESSION['Id'] = $row['Username']; work there.

Comment: It's been a while since I last used the `session_` functions directly - but try commenting out `session_name` in your view page - or add `session_name('Id');` to the top of your `login.php`.

Comment: @RobinRai in php there's a built in function that checks if your password matches the hashed. 

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

and for $_SESSION['Id'] = $row['Username'], shouldn't that give the SESSION[id] allow it to match a username, thereby giving the session a value

Comment: Also, for vanilla PHP, `session_` stuff should happen before your includes, or anything else for that matter (unless you have a shared session starting include). Good habit to get into.

Comment: @PhillipElm Oh, thanks. Yeah I tried commenting that line out and adding the line above the login.php and it didn't work.

Comment: @DarkRain Sorry for that i didn't realize it. But how does $_SESSION['Id'] = $row['Username']; works out here as $_SESSION['Id'] won't have any value on it.

Comment: @DarkRain Remove `session_regenerate_id();` and try

Comment: @RobinRai doesn't it check the rows in the database and find the id that is matched with the username?

Comment: @DarkRain Ok i will add code in answer. Please try it

Comment: @Gunaseelan Yeah, I tried that

Comment: @DarkRain Check `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see what is in session

Comment: @Gunaseelan oh, it's null. Does that mean it's dropping sessions?

Comment: @DarkRain There is no session variable in the html page. So session is not passed from the process page.Try this , Remove `session_name('Id')` and see

Comment: @Gunaseelan I tried that and it didn't work

This is what I get https://imgur.com/a/LlaBV

Comment: Replace `header ("Location: 'mywebsite');` with `header ("Location: 'mywebsite");` in both places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are effectively using different sessions on your two pages.

In your html page you set your session name to "Id" by using

```
session_name('Id');
```

while your login.php page use the default session name since nothing else has been declared.

Ensure that the session name is the same on all pages that need to share the same session, either by declaring the same session name or by using the default.

You are also putting yourself into a new session on every pageload of your html page by using

```
session_regenerate_id();
```

You must remove that too.

Additionally, you must store the username from the database in a temporary variable before adding it to the session, since `$row` will be `null` by the time you try to add it to the session (`mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns `null` when there are no more rows to fetch).

Comment: I tried doing default session names and they did not work.

Comment: Try removing the session_regenerate_id(); from your html page too. It too effectively puts you into a new session every time you load the page.

Comment: Did you try both of them together? I.e. remove both session_name() and session_regenerate_id().

Comment: Yup I did that as well

Comment: I just tested it and those changes definitely make the session work properly. So if it still doesn't work, there must be some issue with your login logic.

Do you store the password in your database as plaintext or as a hash?

Comment: I store it as a hash, did you try it with my code up top?

Comment: Can you verify whether the login logic works either by redirecting to different urls depending on success/failure or by outputting something different in your login.php depending on success/failure?

Comment: Yeah the login logic is fine. I can go to 2 different web pages based on success / failure with the line  "if (password_verify($Userpassword , 
 }" in the php.

Comment: Strange, I used your exact code (except for the database part) for my test and it works flawlessly. What's in your DbConfig.php? Maybe there's a conflict in there.

Comment: Could it perhaps be a drop in session? It says the var_dump($_SESSION) is null

<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "dpw_recyclopedia";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
 
?>

That is all that is in my dbconfig

Comment: I think I found the issue. mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) returns null when there are no more rows left to read. This means that $row will be null when you are trying to put the username into the session at $_SESSION['Id'] = $row['Username']; Try to store the username in a variable like you do with the password.

Comment: Yup that was it! Thank you so much.

Comment: You're very welcome. I have updated my answer to include all the issues now. Please mark it as accepted so others can see that a solution has been found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (change if(password_verify) part):

```
if (password_verify($Userpassword , $storedPassword)) {
    $sql = "SELECT Username, Password FROM Users WHERE Username = '".$user."'";
    if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $_SESSION['Id'] = $row['Username'];
                header ("Location: 'mywebsite');
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
```